# Writing multi lingual text in PDF

Tags: text, multilingual

My intention is to write a PDF file with multi lingual text using Arial, Nirmala (simple one I chose) font. But after using PDF doc for few months time, am unable to get the right mix of objects usage in writing to PDF after many failed attempts using standards and specifications from Truetype, CIDFontType0 (Truetype), Embedding and non embedding, Encoding Identity-H and without encoding.

I need to print a Greek char and a Indian char.
Attached is a sample of my generated output with a Greek Alpha using Arial.

<</Font <</FXF1 8 0 R >>>>endobj

Contents: 7 0 obj..<</Length 107 /Filter /FlateDecode >>stream..x..wI-.LN.rwRH.V0....<.}..s0T<..O.P.)DA.-..P.P!$M..B.......@...............!.+$7Z#b........]lH..k.B...#~"...endstream.endobj

Font: 8 0 obj..<</Type /Font /BaseFont /Arial /Subtype /TrueType /FirstChar 1/LastChar 5/Widths [ 750 666 ]./FontDescriptor 9 0 R >>endobj

FontDescriptor: 9 0 obj..<</Ascent 1060/CapHeight 718/Descent -307/Flags 32/FontBBox [-1171 -328 2506 1166] /FontName /Arial/FontStretch /Normal /FontWeight 400/ItalicAngle 0/StemV 68/XHeight 531/FontFile2 10 0 R /Type /FontDescriptor >>

I embedded the whole font file and am able to use the font file binary in another document to generate its text, so, I guess font file is properly compressed.
Other values I used my default usage and local samples using such values.

I need to know , how to embed only a portion of the font file in pdf.
I also need to know, how the text input to be given, and how am I to decide to give a character ID or glyph index if needed to be given in input string, so that the reader will understand the character to print.

If I get a better way forward, I can extend it to cover a larger text.

Output file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15xEQWuRZALocJT2tTtUAvVK3X4Crd47L/view?usp=drivesdk

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you.  So even without embeding my doc does not render the letter alpha. Any suggestions ? Or Any mistakes can you correct from what is given objects.  ?

Comment: So, in order to insert a non latin character from simple true type font like arial, eg. Alpha, what approach is needed.?

Whatever the pdf spec doc says is not working for me, despite using font embedding & Identity-H encoding.?

Otherwise is it possible to change the code page 1252 to 1253 etc..?

Comment: the content stream has the text this only: (X)<0391> 0391 for Greek alpha.
Others are minor values only. Encoding: Identity-H, any thing else you need...?
I tried both true type and CID Type0, with and without embedding.

Comment: I agree that the writer's decision to do, but Arial "A" char itself writes one writer does as CIDFont, another as TrueType, Acrobat does not even mention font name. If all these goes, then how come the PDF Spec Doc is complied with...? Just wanted to understand what you wanted to convey (little deeper)... Even few Acrobat samples of mine does not even follow rules of the spec doc. So how come a programmatic PDF writer to comply with, am not able to get a path clear...

Comment: Yes, This is fine for Type0 standard fonts. This works for me.
But for True type simple fonts and CID composite fonts, pls give similar answer (if not Greek Alpha then some other char sets of simple Arial like Hebrew etc, or Indian text using Nirmala etc). 
Thank you for your response.

Comment: Okay, so assuming I need only TrueType Arial font, to print non English character, with font embedding, what is the text input am I supposed to give. like for Greek alpha 
 <0391> or any other value, if so how to retrive that value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input a multilingual text string to output a PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73712617/input-a-multilingual-text-string-to-output-a-pdf-file)

Comment: thats not working, had tried several attempts

Comment: Updated output file for view

Comment: Please check now.